When Is Periodic Profit-Taking Better Than Holding Until Maturity?
I am conducting a comparative analysis of two investment strategies using Monte Carlo simulations: periodic profit-taking and holding the investment until maturity. Specifically, I am simulating price paths for a cryptocurrency (Polkadot) over a 90-day period with 1,000 iterations. The initial parameters are as follows:
Initial price: $4.1
Final price: $5.8
Initial investment: $15,000
Days: 90
Number of simulations: 1,000
The daily returns are assumed to follow a normal distribution with a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 0.02.
Scenario 1: Holding the Investment Until Maturity
In this scenario, the entire investment is held for 90 days, and the final value is computed at the end of this period. The average final value and profit are calculated across all simulations.
Scenario 2: Periodic Profit-Taking
In this scenario, profits are periodically taken whenever the value of the investment exceeds the initial principal of $15,000. The principal is reinvested each time a profit is taken. The average total profit taken and the final value of the principal at the end of the period are computed across all simulations.
The results indicate a slight difference in the average final value and profits between the two strategies, with the periodic profit-taking strategy showing marginally higher total returns.
In my super simple analysis I get the following:
Scenario 1: Holding for 90 Days and Selling at the End
Average Final Value: $15047.68
Average Profit: $47.68

Scenario 2: Periodic Profit-Taking
Average Total Profit Taken: $45.57

Q: Under what conditions or assumptions does periodic profit-taking outperform a hold-until-maturity strategy in terms of risk-adjusted returns? Specifically, what factors (e.g., volatility, mean return, frequency of profit-taking) would make periodic profit-taking a more advantageous strategy than holding the investment until the end of the period?
Appreciate if you share your experience.

Optional Stopping Theorem and Normal distribution of returns => neither scenario outperforms one another.

I think what Attack68 is saying is that, before you ran the simulation, there's no way to know which one will come out better. if you took a different $\sigma$ and tried the same thing, you may get the opposite result. The theory says that neither is necessarily better than the other. It depends on how the stock moves in the future which is obviously not known beforehand.
